# How do you defer interpolation of an Angular directive parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have the following:

```
 <my-directive value="{{row.id}}" /> <!-- row not defined -->
```

Then inside of your directive:

```
 <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
     <a ng-click="/path/{{value}}">..</a>
 </a>
```

Where value is the same value as passed into the directive. How do I defer the evaluation of the attribute?g

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @Stewie reason is rather complex, I'm building a Angular grid view and I need to pass in to the grid what the click function for each row should look like. It relies on values from each row.

Comment: What does your directive look like?

Answer (score 0):

To your question:
A) You could use $timeout in your directive's link function and set a second parameter when the timeout expires. 
B) or, you could use $watch if you are waiting for it to be set and then conditionally update that second parameter.

However, I suspect the problem may come from an issue in you link and loop. Perhaps something like what is below would work better. Note the removal of the ng-click.

```
 <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
     <a href="/path/{{row.somekeyInRow}}">..</a>
 </a>
```

Comment: I want `value="{{row.id}}"`to be treated as just as string and not evaluated by angular. Row doesn't exist in the scope of the top level, it only exists in the inner scope of the directive.

Comment: you would need to put it in single quotes. `value="'{{row.id}}'"`